# Como escrever tachado em comentarios

Tags: suporte

É possível escrever **<s>tachado</s>** assim nos comentários? Se sim, alguém poderia dar um exemplo de como fazer ?

Comment: Até pode, mas teria que ter um bom embasamento para que seja atendido. Sinceramente, não vejo muita possibilidades disso não. É mais provável até que alguém chegue aqui com uma solução gambiarrada ao invés disso, rs

Comment: Gostaria de entender a necessidade :)

Comment: Será que isso <del>funciona></del>

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento a necessidade é zuar nos comentários né, eu ia escrever assim: "sua <s>gambiarra</s> técnica é muito boa!" mas sem o tachado perde o efeito da brincadeira... rsrsrsr

Comment: @SneepSNinjA entendi, realmente parece uma boa (e única) utilidade. Hehehehe :D

Comment: Foi o que eu disse. Temos que evitar coisas que possam ofender @SneepSNinjA. Se eu vesse um comentário desse eu ia sinalizar.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters o que (penso) escrevo não é ofensivo e quem quer fazer isso, o fará de uma maneira ou de outra

Comment: Tem [essa pergunta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135219) no SOen, e o que dizem é para tentar usar [u̶n̶i̶c̶o̶d̶e̶](http://adamvarga.com/strike/) para isso.

Comment: Só acho que se o recurso já existe para utilizar na pergunta poderia também ser utilizado nos comentários

Comment: Mas na pergunta ninguém tem coragem de ofender, já que ganha votos negativos, né. Aí os espertos usam comentários.

Comment: sabia que alguém ia encontrar um jeito :P

Comment: @WallaceMaxters a questão da coragem fica a cargo de cada um, se fizer tanto na pergunta quanto no comentário será sinalizado e removido, é simples, não acho que a ferramenta em si seja um mau

Comment: @SneepSNinjA espera que entenda que não existe outro motivo para usar strike nos comentários a não ser esse que você mesmo citou. Poderia ser legal para marcar links, por exemplo, que estão quebrados, mas os comentários depois de um tempo não podem ser alterados. Já o post pode.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento a dúvida sim, mas o pedido de novo recurso não. Os negativos, acredito eu, são por causa dessa tag em questão. Leia os comentários na resposta para entender melhor.

Comment: Precisamos de mais perguntas negativadas aqui no Meta. Isso não afeta a reputação em nada e dá um pouquinho de emoção, só +1, +1, +1, +1, cansa... Parabéns pela pergunta impopular, +1!

Comment: @brasofilo concordo mas o principal que precisamos é que as pessoas participem, existem muitos poucos que participam de verdade, dificilmente conseguimos promover um bom debate, e os que chegam novos acham que o meta só serve pra problemas que ocorrem no exato momento, o que passou não tem valor. Discutindo com um novo usuário mas bastante ativo ele se recusou a ler os linda que mandei do META e prefere seguir o que ele mesmo acha certo... Ou seja o META deve ter menos de 1% de participação :/ - tem muitos que sabem dar downvotes mas não sabem ou não expõe suas opiniões

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, eu tive esta idéia, [Oferecer suporte no Meta ao colocar uma pergunta em suspenso](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2009/201), mas caiu em ouvidos moucos lá no Metão... vou perguntar pro Math, naquela época ele não era mod...

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, ah, sim, olha este meta-formato fenomenal que o pessoal do Puzzle & Code Golf arrumou: [Sandbox for Proposed Challenges](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/23668)

Comment: Acabei deixando essa pergunta apenas como **suporte** e abri outra específica para o novo-recurso http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4784/novo-recurso-tachado-nos-coment%C3%A1rios

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Não acho que seria algo necessário, pelo contrário, poderia "poluir" os comentários que são para tirar dúvidas relacionadas a perguntas/respostas.

Existe uma pergunta [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135209) sobre essa mesma questão.

Para realizar o que quer, você pode postar [Unicodes](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) com a formatação.

Existe sites, [como este](http://adamvarga.com/strike/) que fazem o que precisa. Basta digitar o que deseja e copiar e colar o resultado nos comentários.

Eu particularmente acho muita "poluição" e não vejo utilidade, mas está aí uma forma.

O exemplo funcionandopode ser visto [neste comentário.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4773/como-escrever-tachado-em-comentarios#comment15604_4773)

Comment: i̶n̶t̶e̶r̶e̶s̶s̶a̶n̶t̶e̶ up vote a favor da resposta que mostra a solução, e dow na pergunta, é ou não útil essa questão/Resposta? Por favor parem com a hipocrisia de julgar o motivo e minha pessoa, a coitadinha da ferramenta não tem culpa se alguns a usam de maneira banal como o AP.

Comment: Obrigado @Randrade por contribuir, caso tenha criado um monstro, poderemos no futuro discutir a remoção da tal ferramenta ;D

Comment: @SneepSNinjA Eu não votei negativo na pergunta. Não creio que eu concordar ou não com a pergunta mereça downvote. Apenas coloquei minha opinião na resposta. Mas também não acho que mereça upvote, para mim é uma pergunta normal.

Comment: comentei citando no geral deve ter pessoas que dão down na pergunta e up na resposta esses a quem me referi quando disse hipocrisia. Porque em vez de analisar a ferramenta e sua utilidade analisam a pessoa que a utiliza

Comment: @SneepSNinjA o problema é a tag novo-recurso, acho que poderia deixar do jeito que estava antes, pois votos positivos em novo-recurso indica apoio da comunidade.

Comment: @Math como a resposta do Randrade faz referência a um meio externo ao SOPT como solução acho que deveria ficar a tag pois não tem um meio direto de se fazer o tachado, mas se não for uma sugestão e sim um aviso cabal então deixe mais claro que faço o ajuste

Comment: @SneepSNinjA Como o Math disse. Votos positivos é a comunidade apoiando, querendo a mudança. Negativo mostra que a mudança não é necessário. Utilizando essa tag é como se fosse uma enquete, se eu entendi bem o que o Math disse.

Comment: é isso mesmo, quero saber se a comunidade quer a ferramenta ou não, uma vez que diretamente não dá p/ fazer, e agora que sabemos uma gambiarra isso só irá retardar o tempo do post, e não efetivamente irá impedir o que proponho

Comment: @Randrade exato

Comment: Ou seja pode dar down, não fico triste se é a vontade da comunidade, mas que então comecem a dar down na resposta também e comecem a propor uma solução para que essa gambiarra não venha a ser praticada aqui

Comment: @SneepSNinjA Então, neste caso os downvotes em sua pergunta são justificáveis, e não um "sinal de hipocrisia".

Comment: opa a hipocrisia é apoiar a gambiarra e não apoiar o meio 'oficial' de se fazer a coisa

Comment: @SneepSNinjA Concordo em parte. Pois na resposta eu mostro a discurssão sobre o mesmo assunto no Meta.SE. Não apenas mostro a g̶a̶m̶b̶i̶a̶r̶r̶a̶ (essa é uma das utilidades?). Mas sobre a resposta, na primeira frase eu digo que sou contra, pode ser por isso os upvotes.

Comment: quer ver que daqui a pouco tempo irá aparecer vários comentários com essa gambiarra, mas apoiar oficialmente até agora só 1, então só 1 e mais eu que teríamos esse direito, uma vez que é o que parece sermos os únicos a curtir a ideia

Comment: @Randrade o seu posicionando eu compreendo perfeitamente, não há contradição em mostrar que é possível fazer, seria como mostrar uma falha de segurança e ser contra explorar essa falha ok