# novo recurso - Tachado nos comentários

Tags: novo-recurso, status-recusado

Já que existe uma maneira "trabalhosa" de se fazer o tachado nos comentários, respondido [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4773/como-escrever-tachado-em-comentarios). Venho através desta pedir o voto da comunidade em favor do desenvolvimento dessa ferramenta no próprio site SOPT.

Como na pergunta [anterior](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4773/como-escrever-tachado-em-comentarios) acabei focando na discussão do suposto caos e desordem que esta ferramenta poderá vir a trazer, supostos pesos e medidas indicam que isso seria piorar em vez de melhorar vou deixar minha opnião tanto dos pontos positivos quantos negativos.

1. Os efeitos das fontes ( Negrito, Italico, Sublinhado e **tachado**)  são sem dúvida uma boa forma de dar destaque, estilização.
2. É através dessa estilização que podemos dar ao leitor o sentido certo do texto conduzindo eles para que o texto possa ser **interpretado da maneira que o autor pensou**.
3. Foi inventado para **desvalidar** algo que foi **dito**, **mudança de idéia** ou **correção** e que **deve** permanecer registrado.

---

Vamos aos exemplos de uso: ( da maneira correta da qual foi concebida o seu propósito )

Eu faço uma pergunta e digo que uma variável é x=11.90

Logo começa a aparecer respostas com base nesse valor.

Eu **Edito** a pergunta e mudo o valor para x=11,95 e uma das respostas continua com 11.90, alguém vai no comentário perguntar o porque desse valor, uma vez que na Pergunta esta atualmente outro valor.

Um simples comentário usando esse tachado resolveria a questão de forma rápida
*“**poderia revisar sua resposta  <s>X=11.90</s> x=11.95**”*

Pronto isso é suficiente para que o dono da resposta note que o valor da variável mudou.

Obs: Este efeito também é muito útil quando se quer dar a impressão de mudança de indicativos de promoções, do tipo de <s>R$ 12,00</s> por R$ 9,90.

---

Outro exemplo:

Criei um comentário: ***“ a necessidade é zuar nos comentários”***

**Arrependido** quero **corrigir isso**, mas já se passaram 16 horas, então não é mais permitido edição, não quero **apagar** porque quero deixar uma resposta registrada, se eu só apagar e registrar outra terei que explicar o ***“porque, quando e onde”*** se eu usa-se o tachado seria simples.

Crio outro comentário: ***“ a necessidade é <s>zuar</s> estilizar corretamente nos comentários”***

pronto olha só como é simples mudar de ideia dessa maneira, em vez de fazer todo um caminho longo onde teria que dar explicações, talvez indicar “ref ao comentário 6”, mas daí alguém removeu um comentário anterior a esse, então deixou de ser o 6, vou ter que retificar o comentário que retifica o que foi apagado vai complicando em vez de simplificar.

Eu não vejo o porquê de não termos uma ferramenta dessas, vejo pessoas resistentes a mudanças, que cai matando uma boa idea com um simples “**não é necessidade**”, bem comprar um avião pode não ser necessário para você, mas pode ser para outra pessoa, pense realmente na comunidade como um todo e não olhe para você, votar contra e usar o voto com esse pensamento “**eu não usaria, então voto down**” esse pensamento é **errado**, por que? Simplesmente porque você esta pensando em você mesmo e não no coletivo, o seu pensamento deveria ser **“isso será legal para os outros mesmo que isso para mim não faz diferença nenhuma?”**

Demais casos e suposições a respeito do uso indevido seja **qualquer** tipo de ferramenta aqui no SOPT temos pessoas excelentes capazes de sinalizar, remover, e **ensinar** as pessoas a usarem de forma correta **todas** as ferramentas que **já existem** e que **irão de existir** aqui.

Obrigado por sua atenção.

Comment: Acho que para comentários era escusado uma vez que tens só 5 minutos para editar.

Comment: Pois é @JorgeB. e depois dos 5min não podemos mais mudar corrigir, a ferramenta poderia ser útil nesse caso

Comment: Mesmo que o tempo seja **liberado** criar outro comentário **corrigindo** com o tachado talvez fique melhor, pois assim demais comentários já postados não ficariam obsoletos ou sem sentido após alguém editar um anterior

Comment: Eu não acho isso relevante nos comentários.

Comment: ok rsrsr, e isso seria legal para os outros mesmo que isso para mim não faz diferença nenhuma?

Comment: @JorgeB. ok rsrsr, e isso seria legal para os outros mesmo que isso para m̶i̶m̶ você não faz diferença nenhuma?

Comment: Isso não podia ser mantido na outra pergunta?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento depois de 5 min não, e mesmo que o tempo fosse liberado, quero deixar esse destaque em tachado, para insinuar que isso foi retirado do próprio texto da pergunta, o Jorge esta com o pensamente de que "pra mim não serve" onde eu já fiz menção que isso é um pensamento errado de julgar pois a melhoria é para a comunidade e não para 1 pessoa

Comment: Eu acho é que tinha que por o tachado no markdown todo, nao só nos comentários. Esse negócio de usar HTML eu sou contra. (Mas sou obrigado a usar <br> pra separar os títulos, mas isso pq nao arrumam o CSS dos cabeçalhos) http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1483/70

Comment: Postei como questão separada.

Answer (score 3):

Antes de qualquer coisa, vamos entender o que são os **comentários**.

Na página sobre [comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) do site temos a seguinte definição:

> Os comentários são observações temporárias do tipo "post-it" deixadas em uma pergunta ou resposta. Eles podem receber votos a favor (mas não votos contra) e ser sinalizados, mas não geram reputação. Não há um histórico de revisões e, quando os comentários são excluídos, eles deixam de ser exibidos definitivamente.

E na mesma página temos os seguintes tópicos:

> ### Quando devo fazer um comentário?
>
> Você deve deixar um comentário caso queira:
>
> - Solicitar esclarecimentos ao autor;
> - Fazer críticas construtivas que ajudem o autor a melhorar a publicação;
> - Adicionar informações relevantes, porém menores ou temporárias a uma publicação (por exemplo, um link a uma pergunta relacionada, ou um alerta a autor de que a pergunta foi atualizada).
>
> ### Quando não devo fazer comentários?
>
> Os comentários não são recomendados nos seguintes casos:
>
> - Sugestão de correções que não alteram fundamentalmente o significado da publicação; em vez disso, faça ou sugira uma edição;
> - Responder à pergunta ou fornecer uma solução alternativa a uma resposta existente; em vez disso, publique uma resposta propriamente dita (ou edite uma existente para ampliá-la);
> - Fazer elogios que não acrescentam novas informações ("+1, excelente resposta!"); em vez disso, vote a favor da resposta e devolva a boa ação;
> - Fazer críticas que não acrescentam nada construtivo ("-1, veja os comentários anteriores, seu malandro!"); em vez disso, vote contra (e dê uma resposta melhor ou vote a favor de uma, caso apropriado);
> - Abrir uma discussão secundária ou debater um ponto controverso; em vez disso, use o bate-papo;
> - Discutir sobre o comportamento na comunidade ou políticas do site; em vez disso, use meta.

Em todo a página é usado a palavra **temporário**. Isso, a meu ver, não é por coincidência. Na verdade, comentários são apenas para ajudar as perguntas/respostas. Se uma pergunta/resposta possui muitos comentários é porque tem algo de errado com ela, e o ideal seria editar e/ou fechar e abrir outra.

Mas, já falei demais sobre isso, vamos à sua questão, especificamente sobre os três pontos que citou.

> 1º Os efeitos das fontes ( Negrito, Italico, Sublinhado e tachado) são sem dúvida uma boa forma de dar destaque, estilização.

Realmente, mudar a formatação chama mais atenção da pessoa, ela irá olhar de forma diferente para o comentário. Mas se colocar o <strike>tachado</strike>, porque não adicionar para mudar a cor, piscar, subir e descer... Em outras palavras, iria virar o "carnaval" SOpt. Não é a intenção do site, por isso as três opções básicas.

> 2º É através dessa estilização que podemos dar ao leitor o sentido certo do texto conduzindo eles para que o texto possa ser interpretado da maneira que o autor pensou.
>   Acho que se você necessita desse recurso para "dar sentido" no texto, tem algo muito errado. A final, você tem 600 caracteres para se expressar, precisar de uma formatação para isso não é o ideal.
>
> 3º Foi inventado para desvalidar algo que foi dito, mudança de idéia ou correção e que deve permanecer registrado.

Quem está participando dos comentários não serão avisados quando "tachar" a sua palavra, e uma edição não deveria ser com esse propósito. Se quer corrigir, nada mais justo que mostrar que realmente tem algo errado e postar a forma correta, creio que 600 caracteres seja o bastante para isso.

Vamos pegar por exemplo [esse seu comentário].([javascript loop com sleep](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109165/javascript-loop-com-sleep#comment226027_109165))

> > @DanielOmine n̶o̶ ̶m̶e̶u̶ ̶c̶a̶s̶o̶ eu simplifiquei a pergunta justamente para poupar entendimento do propósito, que no meu caso seria disparar ajax para paginas php que faz uso de $_SESSION que essa não tinha tempo de gravar na session, então dei foco no problema que era disparar no javascript com intervalos, o propósito eu tenho certeza que não é duplicada. – SneepS NinjA

Nesse caso eu não vi sentido do `strike` neste comentário. Com ele ou sem ele o sentido seria o mesmo. **Eu simplifiquei** e **<strike>no meu caso</strike>** poderiam ser facilmente colocados na mesma frase, uma simples pontuação daria o entendimento necessário.

### Conclusão

Em alguns casos de utilização, em minha opinião, vai contra o real motivo dos comentários descrito no site. Claro, vemos muitas vezes comentários totalmente diferente do que foi dito, mas não são as funções deles. Não há porque alguns erros justificarem outros.
Diante disso, eu não acho que esse recurso traria vantagens para o site, pelo contrário, só teríamos comentários com palavras grifadas, muitas fezes erroneamente.

Comment: Se observar com atenção a palavra temporário não é **regra** [..porém menores **ou** temporárias..] e com certeza também não é praticado pois há muitos comentários bem antigos e não há necessidade de serem removidos. No exemplo que usou pode ser desnecessário, mas isso não responde aos 2 exemplos que usei aqui na perguta como recurso e com certeza não se limita a isso também

Comment: Outra coisa também é o carnaval de sobe e desce, smiles e emoticons etc., creio que discutir isso sim é irrelevante uma vez que isso não esta sendo proposto, e sim estilização do **texto** e não adição de um novo tipo de conteúdo.

Comment: Ao falar de **temporário** me referia a definição: `Os comentários são observações temporárias...`. Não quis falar sobre todos os seus exemplos, pois daria o mesmo sentido. Se você quer avisar que algo foi alterado, basta escrever que algo foi alterado. Sobre a parte de corrigir palavras, se você pode editar o comentário, basta editar a palavra, não precisa especificamente "tachar".

Comment: Eu acho que essa discussão toda faria mais sentido se a pergunta fosse "novo recurso: tachado no markdown". Faz uma falta danada no markdown, e se lá fosse posto, os comentários poderiam herdar isso de brinde e todo mundo ficaria feliz.

Comment: E como eu disse, nem todos sabem usar esse recuro. Se não sabem usar, muitos não sabem entender. Tenho certeza que já viu esse recurso sendo usado de forma errada, eu particularmente já vi em muitos sites.

Comment: @Randrade depois de 5 mim, não da para corrigir o comentário :/ se eu quiser avisar que algo foi alterado cai no caso de ter que ficar dando a **explicação** como você mesmo disse, em vez de explicar eu poderia simplesmente usar a ferramenta **explicitando** com o tachado

Comment: @SneepSNinjA Nesse caso entra a questão do usuário entender também. Esse uso não é uma "convenção", pode ser interpretado de outra forma.